# How can I get Flip 3D task switching in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-vista

Is it possible to get [Flip 3D task switching](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-Windows-Flip-3D) in Windows XP? I want it to be activated by <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, like it is in Windows Vista and 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All hope is not lost! You can achieve a similar effect with an external tool called [**Shock Aero 3D**](http://www.docs.kr/entry/Download-Shock-Aero3D-en) :)

[image]

Comment: +1 also... Molly and John T always have the answer! God damn it I need to know a lot

Answer (score 2):

**[WinFlip](http://winflip.en.softonic.com/)** offers task switching effects of Vista for Windows XP.

[image]

WinFlip is freeware and portable.

Comment: +1 but the A-B-C-D-E is )(*!"&*" Ugly!

Comment: @r0ca - what you find ugly will speed up matters tremendously (at least for keyboard jockeys) as you can press the corresponding key on key on the keyboard to bring up the desired window to the front. :)

Comment: You are right! I got to admit

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible. Only with Vista and Windows 7

Comment: aw ok, I thought it was possible

Comment: As mentionned by John, you can have third party apps that can "emulate" the Windows-tab effect on XP but the kernel has not been programmed to have it built-in.

Answer (score 0):

I found both Shock Aero 3d and WinFlip buggy, and ended up using this nice and adjustable thing http://www.ntwind.com/software/vistaswitcher.html

No 3D, just 2D, but that's a good thing. This is for XP, Vista, and 7.